# Wireguard Unable to Complete Handshake on Android only 4G network

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, wireguard

I have a Wireguard server on my home network which works fine on all my devices, including my phone when it's connected on Wi-Fi. The problem comes when I disconnect from the Wi-Fi and go on 4G, now my phone is unable to complete the handshake with my server.

On my router, I have UDP port 51820 forwarded to my Wireguard server.
On my phone, I connect to the VPN using the DNS name (vpn.mydomain.tld:51820)

I've enabled kernel logging for Wireguard to help me troubleshoot this but sadly I haven't been able to find what's wrong with my setup.

Here are the logs on my server that appear when I'm trying to connect from my phone (via 4G)

```
Mar 23 17:49:36 wireguard kernel: [448095.663902] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 9893 created for peer 16
Mar 23 17:49:45 wireguard kernel: [448104.009541] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 16 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40061)
Mar 23 17:49:45 wireguard kernel: [448104.009546] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 16 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40061)
Mar 23 17:49:45 wireguard kernel: [448104.010284] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 9893 destroyed for peer 16
Mar 23 17:49:45 wireguard kernel: [448104.010286] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 9894 created for peer 16
Mar 23 17:49:50 wireguard kernel: [448109.069901] wireguard: wg0: Receiving handshake initiation from peer 16 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40061)
Mar 23 17:49:50 wireguard kernel: [448109.069903] wireguard: wg0: Sending handshake response to peer 16 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:40061)
Mar 23 17:49:50 wireguard kernel: [448109.070073] wireguard: wg0: Keypair 9894 destroyed for peer 16
```

On my phone, I see the following:

```
peer(...) - Sending handshake initiation
peer(...) - Handshake did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
peer(...) - Sending handshake initiation
peer(...) - Handshake did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
peer(...) - Sending handshake initiation
```

Since it works fine when I'm connected to my home Wi-Fi, I'm at a loss as to what to look for other that port forwarding, but that works fine as far as I can tell.

Here is the wg0.conf on my server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.3/32
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT;  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 10.10.10.0/24 -o pia -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -d 10.10.10.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -d 10.10.10.0/24 -o pia -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [removed]

[Peer]
PublicKey = [removed]
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.245/32
Endpoint = 10.10.10.147:60743
```

And the connection file on my phone (running Android 11):

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.245/24
DNS = 10.10.10.2
PrivateKey = [removed]

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = vpn.mydomain.tld:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
PublicKey = [removed]
```

I've made sure the keys are matching but since the connection works fine when connected to my Wi-Fi, I don't think the config file is to blame.

I have UFW installed on the server, with the following config:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51820/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
10050                      ALLOW       Anywhere
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
10050 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

However I disabled it to make sure it wasn't interfering, and it didn't change anything.
At this point I don't know what is wrong nor what to search for to help me in figuring this out so any help will be welcome

**EDIT:** I kind of figured out where the issue is coming from. Im my wg0.conf, I have the following part in my PostUp: `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 10.10.10.0/24 -o pia -j MASQUERADE`
This line is meant to route all outgoing traffic through another tunnel, however, it also has the side effect of making my WireGuard server respond to my external client through another IP (i.e. I'm connecting from my phone on 4G to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and because of that line, it's responding to the connection request via yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy), which is why my client won't connect.
When I remove this routing rule, I can connect just fine from outside my network, but now of course, my traffic isn't re-routed through my second tunnel.
Is there a way I can keep this rule, or at least a similar rule that will route external traffic through the other VPN, whilst responding to my phone's connection request via my eth0 device? Since my phone will be connecting from 4G, I can't expect the IP address it will connect from, sp I can't add a similar routing rule only for my phone.

Comment: tcpdump the connection to see if packets arrive and go out again.

Comment: @user9517 I'm not familiar with that tool but I checked and nothing comes up when I attempt the handshake from my phone, however in the kern.log I can see the server receives the handshake request. Used `sudo tcpdump -i wg0` command

Comment: @user9517 actually scratch that, I used a proper grep to see traffic, and when I'm connected from 4G on the VPN (without successful handshake) I can still see the requests it is doing to the DNS server and other website traffic, however I still seem to have no connection to the internet on the phone itself. For instance, if I try to ping my DNS (directly with the IP address), I get no response. I'm starting to suspect there may be an issue with the configuration on my phone itself.

Comment: From what I can gather, when I'm on Wi-Fi with the VPN on, if I disconnect from Wi-Fi and stay connected on the VPN, I still see traffic with tcpdump, but if I connect the VPN whilst on 4g, I see nothing. I'm not sure what to make of this, but I suspect all the traffic I'm seeing after disconnecting from Wi-Fi is merely "remnants" from when the connection was active

Comment: I found what was causing the problem (see edit), although I don't have a solution yet.

Comment: I did what you said in edit but still handshake didn't complete.So I think it's not a nat problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MASQUERADE`/`POSTROUTING` rules do not change where certain traffics go. Routes do. The problem is that you have a default route (or what's equivalent) that leads traffics into the `pia` tunnel.

You will need to make use of policy routing for the replying traffics from the wireguard server:

```
# ip r add 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table 123
# ip r add default via 192.168.1.1 table 123
# ip rule add iif lo ipproto udp sport 51820 lookup 123
```

The first command could be optional. Make sure you replace `192.168.1.1` and `eth0` with the LAN IP of your router and the interface name of your Ethernet NIC correspondingly. (You can copy them from the output of `ip r`, i.e. routes in the main table.) The number `123` is arbitrary. `iif lo` limits the rule to UDP traffics with source port of `51820` from the host itself (but not such traffics from another host).

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem !

Answer (score 0):

On your android device install windscribe and set it to wireguard mode, then connect. Now check the iptables rules. Unfortunately I'm not good at iptables but there is something in mangle table and mark dns

```
-A st_clear_caught_dns_accept -d 10.255.255.2/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A st_clear_detect -m connmark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A st_clear_detect -m connmark --mark 0x1000000/0x1000000 -j RETURN
-A st_clear_detect -p tcp -m u32 --u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x0&0xffff0000=0x16030000&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x4&0xff0000=0x10000" -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x1000000/0x1000000
-A st_clear_detect -p udp -m u32 --u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x8&0xffff0000=0x16fe0000&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x14&0xff0000=0x10000" -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x1000000/0x1000000
-A st_clear_detect -m connmark --mark 0x1000000/0x1000000 -j RETURN
-A st_clear_detect -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m u32 --u32 "0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0xc>>0x1a&0x3c@0x0&0x0=0x0" -j st_clear_caught
-A st_clear_detect -p udp -j st_clear_caught
-A st_penalty_log -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x1000000/0x1000000
-A st_penalty_log -j NFLOG
-A st_penalty_reject -j CONNMARK --set-xmark 0x2000000/0x2000000
-A st_penalty_reject -j NFLOG
-A st_penalty_reject -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```